# How to receive intent uri?

Tags: android-intent

I have passed below intent in one activity

```
 productListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductDetail.class);
            Uri currentProductUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
            intent.setData(currentProductUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now How to receive intent uri in another activity ? can anyone help me to solve. Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8les.jpg[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change

   ```
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

   to

   ```
   startActivityForResult(intent, URIREQUEST);
   ```
2. define field a top of the classes of the sender and the receiver

   ```
   private static final int URIREQUEST= 1;
   ```
3. In the receiver class, when you got the uri

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   if(uri != null){
       intent.putExtra("Uri", uri.toString());
   }
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
   ```
4. then overide this method in the sender

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

   {
      if(requstcode == URIREQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
      {
        Uri uri_data = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("Uri"));
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am getting an error I have posted screenshot above. can you please look that and tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: I edited my answer, you have to parse the receiving string to the Uri -> `Uri.parse(data.getCharSequenceArrayExtra("Uri"));`

Comment: Still I am getting an error. please check my above screenshot again. thank you

Comment: Try both `Uri.parse(data.getCharSequenceArrayExtra("Uri").toString());` or  Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("Uri"));, one of them should work.

Comment: I have made few changes but when I run it got crash. Can you please look at my git repository and tell me whats wrong in code ?

Comment: you forgot to initiliize the uri.

Comment: I have initialized  Uri uri; Is this correct ? need to make changes ?

Comment: I forgot to added the inttent to setResult, `Intent intent = new Intent();
if(uri != null){
    intent.putExtra("Uri", uri.toString());
}
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` I now get the intent with the string, that i can oarse to a uri.

Comment: I am not receiving any data can you please again check my repo? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code as edit in your question, otherwise it would be to laborsome to answer you.

Comment: @poojagajera, would you please mark my answer as approved then?